# use whitespace as delimiter for xargs arguments

Tags: shell, xargs

Is it possible to pass a string with spaces to xargs and use each *word* as argument?

For example, I am trying something like this. But both word are treated as a single argument.

```sh
echo foo bar | xargs -I {} sh -c 'echo item: {}'
```

I would like to do it with shell and not with bash. Otherwise, I think arrays might be helpful, but they don't exist in shell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `-d` option to specify the delimiter:

```sh
echo 'foo bar' | xargs -I {} -d ' ' sh -c 'echo item: {}'
```

Will result in:

```
item: foo
item: bar
```

> --delimiter=delim, -d delim
> Input  items  are  terminated  by the specified character.  The specified delimiter may be a single character, a C-style character escape such as \n, or an octal or hexadecimal escape code.  Octal and
> hexadecimal escape codes are understood as for the printf command.   Multibyte characters are not supported.  When processing the input, quotes and backslash are not special; every  character  in  the
> input  is taken literally.  The -d option disables any end-of-file string, which is treated like any other argument.  You can use this option when the input consists of simply newline-separated items,
> although it is almost always better to design your program to use --null where this is possible.

Comment: I even read in man pages 2-3 times and didnt spot this. Its clearly written there. `--delimiter=delim, -d delim` ...